# Language to define references between elements in a 2D array/grid

Tags: programming-languages, dsl, multidimensional-array

Has someone created a language which can be used to track/analyze dependencies between grid cells in a generic way?

I'm trying to write a spreadsheet which uses a functional language. What I'm after is something similar to what Excel might use to manage references between cells. The language will be used create a model which can be analysed for optimisation.

Comment: A language?  why would you need a language?  Most people just use a list.

Comment: Sorry original post was very ambiguos. Have edited to add more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Lisp library which was ported to many Lisps (and some other languages)

http://common-lisp.net/project/cells/

At least some ideas there are worth borrowing.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this with the ancient `sc` calculator, a very long time ago.  You build a *dependency graph* based on the contents of the cells.  I know the cells have two-dimensional names, but for simplicity I'm going to name them with single characters.

- Suppose cell `X` contains the formula `Y+1`.  Then you add an edge from `X` to `Y` in the dependency graph.  If `X` contains the formula `Y+0.15*Z` then you add *two* edges: from `X` to `Y` and from `X` to `Z`.
- When you've visited every cell, you've built the entire graph.  Do a topological sort.  If there are no cycles, you're in luck—you can recalculate in topological order.
- You can use the same dependency graph for analysis and optimization.  You can also update the dependency graph incrementally as the contents of cells change.

I hope this is enough to get you started.